# How to automatically fetch images from a website and update desktop image to match (in terminal)?

Tags: terminal, desktop

I'm an astronomer, and I constantly (read: several times per day) check the same website to view the clear sky chart for my observatory. Specifically, the chart found on this webpage:

http://www.cleardarksky.com/c/YerkesObILkey.html

It would be incredibly handy if I were able to automatically set this image to be my laptop's desktop. I know I could set it manually each morning, but that is a hassle (and isn't as nerdy).

Unfortunately, I am not as versed in C and the command line as I perhaps should be. Is there any way to alter my bash profile to automatically download an image from a website and then set that image as my desktop, say, at midnight every 2 days? Barring obvious issues of image resolution and internet connection. A task like this is well out of my skill-set.

Even if this isn't possible/practical, I would be interested to know why not, just as a matter of curiosity.

If it matters, I'm running 10.13.1 High Sierra on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but using this: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25525?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US and creating a web clip of the image on the Dashboard might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options to tackle this:  AppleScript and a Bash (Terminal) script.  Since this needs to happen once per day (meaning *scheduled*) and you want to *guarantee* that the file gets downloaded the moment you're logged in so it can be there when you start and then once again every night at midnight,  I would do this in Bash.

#### Create the Script

The script is going to do two things:

- Download the image
- Set as the background image

The script is fairly simple.  It takes two arguments - URL and the location to save the file.  It will then download it to that folder location:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Bash Script to Download Forecast and Set as desktop background

#User Defined VARs below:

#URL to fetch image 
url="http://www.cleardarksky.com/c/YerkesObILcsk.gif?c=2239204"

#Picture file Location
picFile="/Users/Thomas/Pictures/test.gif"


#Command to retrieve picture and save to defined location
curl -o "${picFile}" "$url"

exit
```

Save it in a convenient location; give it an obvious name like `getSkyForecast.sh`.  Make sure to make the script executable - `chmod +x getSkyForecast.sh`  If you don't do this, the script won't run.

#### Schedule the Script

The following is a bit more complex, because it will run upon login and every 24 hours.

Next, the script needs to be kicked off with `launchd`.  To do this, you need a `plist` (XML file that describes the job)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.user.getSkyForecast</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
      <string>/Users/USERNAME/Path_to_Scripts/getSkyForecast.sh</string>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key> 
  <true/>
  </array>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <array>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>00</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>00</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Save this file as `com.user.SkyForecast` and copy it to the `~/Library/LaunchAgents` directory.

Load it with the command:

```
launchctl load com.user.SkyForecast
```

#### Set the background image

The easiest thing to do is just go into System Preferences and set the Background image to this file (run the script manually first so it creates the file).  When the script runs, it will change the file, not the name so the desktop image will change automatically.

Comment: Just my programming style.

Comment: You state "The script is going to do two things:" the first being "Download the image" which it does, however the second thing "Set as the background image" and there is no code in the script that programmatically does that. That said, you did add a paragraph after the fact "Set the background image" in which you say "... When the script runs, it will change the file, not the name so the desktop image will change automatically.", well did you actually test this? In my test, while the file is overwritten is does not change the actual background shown because the original image is cached.

Comment: You need to code it it so after the file is downloaded either actually programmatically set or once overwritten, using `killall Dock` will force a refresh. My preference would be to programmatically set it and not use `killall Dock`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I ended up going with mostly what Allan suggested, but to work around the problem that user3439894 mentioned, I just added a line to programmatically set the desktop to the desired file on login to the plist, and it now works spotlessly! (I'll test it for a few days, but it seems like it should work)

Comment: @Thomas Sachen, You'll find that if you use the code as defined for the `url` the data is always going to be stale because the URL at the website changes, well the part after the `?` does. You might be able to just use `url='http://www.cleardarksky.com/c/YerkesObILcsk.gif'`, however if that doesn't work then the following will retrieve the actual URL:  `url="http://www.cleardarksky.com$(curl -s http://www.cleardarksky.com/c/YerkesObILkey.html | awk 'match($0,/ src=".*YerkesObILcsk.gif.*" /) {print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-8)}')"`